# Perl EPIC display warnings in console during debug

Tags: perl, epic

Whenever I run a script using the Debug *scriptname* button, the console doesn't display warnings that would usually appear in the console when launching it with the Run *scriptname* button.
Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Installed Eclipse 2019-03 on Ubuntu 19.04. Downloaded EPIC 0.7.7 from http://epic-ide.org/updates/testing/ . I suggest you submit a bug report at [the bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/bugs/). You could also try have a look at the [java source code](https://github.com/jploski/epic-ide) and see if you can fix the bug (?) yourself.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug per se, but rather how the debugger is supposed to work by default.
To be honest, I'm wary of requesting features to the EPIC developers, since another feature I would've found useful (a sorting strategy for variables that ignores sigils) has been rejected.
If you add your comment as an answer I'd gladly award you the bounty. :)

Comment: Hi Massimo. I added a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/bugs/704/)